# How to bind jQuery Calendar to icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I use pop-up datapicker (DHTML Date/Time Selector), which appears due to icon click. But if you change the size of browser window, it stays fixed on the page.

Is there any way to bind calendar to icon this way?

[*Image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH5Qg.png)

```
  Calendar.setup({
      context: self,
      firstDay: 0, /* first day of the week */
      inputField: "firstDateVal", /* id of the input field*/
      button: "date-field-from-button", /* trigger for the calendar (button ID)*/
      align: "Bl",
      singleClick: true,
      showsTime: true,
      timeFormat: "24",
      onSelect: function (){
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery datepicker.
See this documentation : https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/